# Как правильно оформить предложение? 3

Tags: пунктуация

1. Это, после пяти лет развития, точно просчитанный пиар для нового этапа развития завода?
2. Это после пяти лет развития - точно просчитанный пиар для нового этапа развития завода?

Допустимы ли оба варианта? Может быть, можно и совсем без запятых?

Comment: Это риторический вопрос или спрашивают, точно ли просчитан необходимый пиар?

Comment: В данном случае, видимо, имеется в виду точно просчитанный пиар.

Comment: Тогда я бы так сформулировал: Точно ли просчитан (этот) пиар для нового этапа развития завода - после пяти лет развития?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Это, после пяти лет существования, точно просчитанный пиар / для нового развития завода?

(2) После пяти лет существования завода / это точно просчитанный пиар / для его нового развития?

Пояснение

Фраза строится в виде вопроса, потому надо рассчитать ее составные части, разделенные паузами, и при этом сохранить вопросительную интонацию (подъем голоса) в конце. Поэтому объем предложения пришлось немного сократить.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Думаю, слово "этапа" опускать нельзя.